# Ruby extend for object class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, extends

Why for this code I have folowing error?

```
module ForExtend
  def print
    print "ForExtend print method!"
  end
end

class A
end

a = A.new

class << a
  extend ForExtend
end

a.print
```

Result:

```
private method `print' called for #<A:0x005607b26811f8>
(repl):16:in `<main>'
```

In what class/eigenclass lays method `print` in this case? And how can I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why you get the error for calling a private method - there is `Kernel#print` and `Kernel` is included in `Object`, hence objects by default have a private `#print` method.

---

As for where this method lies in this case - it's a class method of the singleton class on `a`:

```
a.singleton_class.print
```

---

As for how to extend the module for `a`, check [@mudasobwa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44965058/2423164).

---

Also note that even if you resolve this, you will get an error for calling `#print` with wrong number of arguments as you redefined it to take no arguments, but call it with one. To call the original implementation when overwriting the method, use `super`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have `A` class, not their instance `a`, extended.

```
module ForExtend
  def print
    puts "ForExtend print method!"
  end
end

class A; end

a = A.new
a.extend ForExtend # ⇐ THIS WILL EXTEND a

a.print
#⇒ "ForExtend print method!"
```